# Image Sizes on a Custom View

Tags: android, image, canvas, bitmap

I was just wondering how images size when drawn on a view using canvas.drawBitmap(), do they stay the same as the raw Bitmap in the relevant drawable folder(LDPI, MDPI, HDPI) or do they scale relative to the screen size?

In order to be constant over different screen sizes, do I need to manually scale the image using createScaledBitmap?

Answer (score 0):

When you **retrieve** a resource it is scaled when not found in the appropriate folder for your screen density. Once a bitmap is loaded (in a `Bitmap` object) it is no longer subject to scaling.

To prevent scaling you can put your resources in the `res/drawable-nodpi` folder.

Comment: So if I place a 50x50 image in the MDPI Folder it will scale to 48x48 on MDPI Phones, and 36x36 on LDPI Phones? However when placed in nodpi it will remain at 50x50? Would scaling based on DPI even work accurately? Since not all MDPI Phones have the same screen dimensions, just similar ones.

Comment: No, a 50x50 image in your mdpi folder would be 50x50 on mdpi phones. There is a formula available for converting between the various dpis somewhere here on stackoverflow. I think the intent of dpi-based scaling is to have resources take up roughly the same amount of on-screen inches regardless of the screen density. It's probably not a good idea to mix `dp` and `px` if your view requires precise alignment.

Comment: oh, so the dpi folders are only in regards to dpi not dpi & px? From Google's documentation I got the impression they where linked.

Comment: Yes, they can be of any pixel size. `dp` is a density-dependent pixel, so if you use these everywhere you should end up with a UI that automatically scales well.